# Error: storage engine 'wiredTiger' The configured storage engine is 'mmapv1' terminating MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB v2.6.10

This is my configuration file, `/etc/mongodb.conf`

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true
```

When I am starting the MongoDB server,

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

This error is showing,

```
exception in initAndListen: 28574 Cannot start server. Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating
```

I am not sure why it is taking `wiredTiger` engine, when I have not configured it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using MongoDB v2.6.10

Probably not. WiredTiger wasn't introduced until 3.0. You likely have had multiple MongoDB binaries on the host and the last one that was running was 3.0+ and using WiredTiger. Move the database files from `/var/lib/mongodb` or set the `--dbpath` to a different directory when you start 2.6.10.

If you want to use databases that are stored in WiredTiger, you'll need to launch a 3.0+ version of MongoDB using WiredTiger, mongodump the database to BSON files, then mongorestore into the 2.6 instance running mmapv1.